# How to implement new Android selection mode while retaining backward compatibility with Android 2.x?

Tags: android, android-listview

According to the [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/new-4-0.html) the new convention for long pressing on a list item is to switch to 'selection mode'.

I realise that the the selection mode is new and heavily integrates with the ActionBar so I am not expecting it to be available for 2.x devices.  I am just wondering what strategies are being used to support the new selection mode for ICS devices while also retaining backward compatibility with 2.x devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shortly, you can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) 4.0 to give you an action bar with action modes that works across Android versions from 2.1 onwards. 4.0 is being released today if I understand correctly.

If you do not wish to do this, use context menus on Android 1.x/2.x devices and action modes on Android 3.0+ devices. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Honeycomb/ActionModeMC) demonstrating using a checklist and an action mode on Android 3.0+ while using context menus on older devices.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the below link:

[Android: Contextual Action Bar for ListView Item Deletion using ActionBarSherlock](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/android/listview/android-contextual-action-bar-for-listview-item-deletion-using-actionbarsherlock/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.